# Выведение нескольких ответов из функции

Tags: python

Я пока новичок в програнье на питоне и во время решения задачи по выводу арифметической прогрессии появилась проблема, которая поставила меня в тупик. Собственно по условиям задачи нужно вывести список ответов, а пока выводится только один(если пак один) или же последний(если их несколько)
Сам код:

```
import sys
import math

i = 1
twins = []
def sumArith(sum) :
    sum = 0
    p = 0
    while p < x:
        sum = sum + num[0]
        num[0] = num[0] + num[1]
        p += 1
    return sum
n = input("Enter count of twins: ")
while i <= int(n):
    num = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers: ").split()))
    i += 1
x = num[2]
print(sumArith(sum))
```

Данные для ввода:

```
2
1 5 8
2 0 3
```

, где 2 - количество пар;
1 - начальное значение, 5 - шаг, 8 - количество членов которые нужно проссумировать

Comment: `sumArith()`  должна вызываться внутри цикла `while`.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку) не без бубнов, но получилось! код прикладываю к основному тексту

Comment: @НинаБрод, если сами нашли решение, то лучше оформить его ответом (вопросы - для вопросов, ответы - для найденных решений, комментарии - для комментариев).

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
import sys
i = 0
answer = []
def arith(a, b, n):
    i = 0
    y = 0
    while i < n:
        x = a + b * i
        y += x
        i += 1
    return y
n = int(input("Enter count: "))
while i < n:
    num = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers: ").split()))
    answer.append(arith(a = num[0], b = num[1], n = num[2]))
    i += 1
print(*answer)
```